# Unable to open pdf file from internal dir

Tags: android, pdf, android-fileprovider

I have a pdf file in location

> /data/user/0/com.app.example/files/User/751f8052e.pdf

now I want to open this file on any PDF reader installed in the device.

This is what I am doing so far

```
Uri imageUri ;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
{
    imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context , context.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority), PDFFile);
}
else
{
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(PDFFile);
}
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
shareIntent.setDataAndType(imageUri , "application/pdf");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
context.startActivity(shareIntent);
```

but it is not opening the pdf file. It gave an error toast

> Can't open the file

Note: I can't copy the file to some other directory.

Thanks

Comment: Is it for the if or the else?

Comment: Why would you not be able to copy that file?

Comment: @greenapps for the else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the indicated private directory you should always use a file provider.

Comment: yes, this is exactly right. I just removed the if and everything is working perfectly. Thanks.